# Make a component stick to screen with a message. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, sticky, semantic-ui-react

What I want to do is to make a nice message box that appears when I'm saving something, I have access to a state that tells me if it's loading or not, but I can't seem to make a component that always appears, no matter how much you've scrolled.

The page is pretty long so wherever they click on a button that triggers this save function, I want this to appear. Where they are.

I've used Semantic UI in this project, and I've tried their sticky component but it only makes the component follow the screen like 50px, I want that number to be infinite.

***Thankful for every answer***

Comment: With pure CSS `position: fixed;` is what you're looking for

Comment: MaterialUI has a [Snackbar](https://material-ui.com/demos/snackbars/) component that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also achieve this with a fixed modal I guess.

Inside your main component:

```
state = {
    // (...)
    isLoading: false
}

// (...)

render() {
    return (
        // Rest of your code
        {this.state.isLoading && <MessageComponent/>} // or however you're rendering the message/modal
        // Rest of your code
    )
}
```

Then in your respective css file styling your MessageComponent:

```
.messageComponent {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did it!, I putted the Message component from semantic in a div and styled the div with css, like you did and also removed margin and such. Works fine now! Thanks!